# Android Studio error 13=permission denied in linux

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

i am using android studio latest version in linux(elementary luna to be specific). I installed jdk, android studio and sdk successfully, android studio opens us perfectly and even i can work on my app. but when i bulid app it gives error 13: permission denied and it opens a black circle image png in new tab.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:compileDebugSources]
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
/home/suUs12/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png
Error:Error: Cannot run program "/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=13, Permission denied
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/suUs12/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.3/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png:
Error: Cannot run program "/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=13, Permission denied
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 30.305 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
```

i dont understand the problem. i did searched on internet and tried many methods like

1. changing permissions with chmod:

   chmod +x /home/alex/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/dx

it executes successfully but with no effect on the problem itself,

2.closing and re-importing project,

3.i also tried this,

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

and i get following result

```
suUs12@suUs12:~/Android/Sdk$ sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lib32stdc++6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'lib32stdc++6' has no installation candidate
```

i guess this is not issue since my system is 32 bit and this is for 64 bit systems.

Can anyone help? since i am really counting on it.

my system configurations:(if useful)

-OS Version: 0.2.1 "Luna" ( 32-bit ),
Built on: Ubuntu 12.04 ( "Precise" )

-installed OpenJdk 7:
java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)

OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm running android studio 1.0.2 on ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) 32 bit and i had the same problem. 
just go to 
"**/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/**" 
and then right click on '**aapt**' file , **properties -> permissions** and check '**Allow executing file as program**'.
then close the window.

In my case,after giving permission for '**aapt**' file, I had to give the same permission for '**dx**' and '**zipalign**' files in the same directory (/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/) and I was able to run my first app using android studio.

Answer (score 4):

**Give Root permission to your android studio by using**

> chmod -777 YourAndroidStudioFolder

Answer (score 2):

This problem is about insufficient authority. If you change your user as 'root' and you open android studio, this problem will be resolved. For ex;

Open Terminal

$ sudo -i

[enter your password] : ********

root@pc-name:~$ cd  /home/username/.../android-studio/bin

root@pc-name:~$ ./studio.sh

Answer (score 1):

If this can help, I solved after giving full execution permissions (`chmod a+x`) to all executables in `/opt/android-bundle/sdk/build-tools/$VERSION/` (`aapt`, `dx` and `zipalign`).

Answer (score 1):

The permissions problem with file not found with aapt wasn't with this file itself but with the *.so files it tries to use. The first thing to do which I didn't at first was run the following sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686 to get the necessary 32 bit *.so files installed. I found out about the missing *.so files by running aapt outside the studio. 
I also found there were a number of files that were read or read write only that needed to be executable in these directories.
android-studio/bin
android-studio/jre/bin
android-studio/jre/jre/bin
android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.14.1/bin

The fsnotifier files and the 2 *.sh file in the first bin directory. All the files in the two jre directories and the gradle file in the last directory needed to be chmod 755. After I did that I no longer get the pop up box about the fsnotifier and the gradle build doesn't get the permission error. Running as root doesn't help when the problem is with files not being executable.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved This Problem By :  Right Click On Main Folder Like Android-Studio and then Go to Properties and then Click On Permission and check CheckBox For Allow Executing File As a Program Then Run Android Studio In Terminal :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the build tool and re download it fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

just reinstall the build tool version and then go into folder where sdk is installed and in build tool version's "aapt" file and change permissions from "property" all to read and write and check mark to "Allow executing file as a program" and then close it.
same problem is solved by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall androidstudio in /opt/ folder.This is a shared folder.I refer to official web's vedio on how to install androidstudio and solve the problem.I almost tried every way on the internet,but it didn't work.In fact,this is just a question about permission.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the partition in which I saved the Sdk was mounted with the defaults option in /etc/fstab, which in turn enabled the default noexec option which forbids execution for all files in that partition.

Then I edited that line in fstab appending exec, resulting in the options list 'user,defaults,exec' for that partition.

Answer (score 0):

I coould resolve the same issue by using the following shell command:

```
chmod 755 -R android-studio
```

You need to grant more privileges.

Answer (score -1):

as error said:

```
Error: Cannot run program "/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=13, Permission denied
```

you don't have permission. just go to `/home/suUs12/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/` and remove `aapt` file.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by:

```
chmod +x /User/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt
chmod +x /User/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/dx
chmod +x /User/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign
```

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio folder, open your terminal and type the following

```
chmod 777 * -R
```

This surely worked like magic for me