# run executable file "Permission denied" on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, linux, android-shell

I tried run `ssserver` on Nexus4 with Android 4.2.2 but can't. The result is "Permission denied". File permissions appear to be normal:

```
shell@mako:/data/local/tmp $ ls -al ssserver                                 
-rwxrwxrwx shell    shell      810284 2019-04-17 09:33 ssserver
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

- reboot device
- disable selinux
- create test.sh in same directory and set execute permission run but get same prompt "Permission denied"
- create android 4.2.2 emulator

The problem seems to be only under Android 5.0 will happen. I tried create Android 4.2.2 emulator and execute `ssserver` it's ok!

Why can't I run `ssserver` on Android device?

Comment: try this link https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15503/how-to-start-ssh-server-in-my-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564677/android-studio-error-13-permission-denied-in-linux/47769011

Comment: thanks, but this is different with me